# how to click on a special coordinate java PC?

Tags: java, coordinates

How can i click on a point of screen with give it coordinates? 
I want to click without touch the screen with mouse.
I want to click with the app.
any idea? 
I know we can click and there is a solution.
I want to use java.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: You asked the same question just five hours ago.  Try to improve the existing one rather than cluttering up the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This can be achieved using the `java.awt.Robot` class.

To do this, first initialize a `Robot` object:

```
Robot r = new Robot();
```

Then, move the coordinate you want to click:

```
r.mouseMove(x, y);
```

Then, press `mouse1` down, like so:

```
r.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
```

Then, quickly release it:

```
r.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
```

What this does is moves the mouse to a specified coordinate on the screen, and then quickly presses and releases the `mouse1`, or left click button, clicking the screen.